# What does "getattr(self, 'something') is true" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I could not figure out what "is True" means in this case:

```
class Answers():
    def get_reference(self):
        return None

    def is_private(self):
        return getattr(self, 'private', False) is True
```

I understand that getattr() will return the value of "private" or it will return False as the default value. So what does the "is True" mean?

Comment: It means that the value of `private` is `True`. Exactly as the syntax says.

Comment: It isn't a dupe of that.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: It means the person who wrote that code doesn't entirely know what they are doing.

Comment: You should create the attribute `private` in the `__init__`-method and don't rely on some getattr-magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's checking whether the getattr call returns True.

Comment: To be more precise, it's checking whether the getattr call returns *exactly* `True`, not some other trueish value.  I don't see why you would do that, though.  It's usually cleaner to convert trueish values to true and falseish  values to false, which you can do with `bool()`.